# CSS for 'Slick' Carousel jQuery plugin not affecting my DOM, despite being loaded

Tags: jquery, css, ruby-on-rails, jquery-plugins, carousel

I am using this jQuery plugin `https://github.com/kenwheeler/slick`, and the JS is working, but the DOM is not reflecting the CSS. The CSS, however, is loaded, because when I go into the dev tools and view the Sources, the file is there. When I inspect the elements, the classes are there, and the classes are also in the CSS, they're just not affecting the appearance of the HTML. Any idea what might be causing this?

The CSS (`slick.css`) is saved in `vendor/stylesheets` and required in `application.css` using `*= require slick`.

There are also fonts included in the plugin, and I'm not sure that I've included these correctly, but I'm not sure that it would make a difference.

Any idea why this is happening?

Mine looks like this:

[image]

Instead of this:

[image]

The sizing/colors/spacing is not translating from the CSS to the DOM, and I'm not sure why. Thanks in advance for any insight!

Comment: Without seeing any code, it will be hard for us to help you figure out what is going on.

Comment: @PatrickAllen, what code would be most beneficial to post?

Comment: @jackerman09 Hey bud, I made this plugin. How exactly do you have this set up? Can I see a screenshot of this without the .slick() method being called? There is another file called style.css that actually makes the padding and margins and colors on the carousel items. Can you see arrows/dots?

Comment: @KenWheeler, thanks for the response. I don't have access to my dev computer at the moment, but before slick was called, the 6 divs (first through sixth) were stacked on top of each other along the left side of the screen. I tried using this both with style.css and without, and at no time did the CSS seem to have any affect on the DOM. I do not see the arrows or dots, although when I commented the CSS related to the arrows I was able to see Next/Previous links the worked as they should. While you're here, can I use this with nested divs without all of them getting "slicked"? Thanks again

Comment: Yeah you just set the 'slide' option to '> div"

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this has been resolved by now, but if anyone else has this issue.  My guess is they're including the `style.css` in the `css` directory which I suspect is for the documentation.  The CSS file that you want to include is in the `slick` directory and called `slick.css`